# Login takes ages after upgrade to XFCE 4.10

Tags: boot, login, xubuntu, xfce

I updated my Xubuntu to XFCE 4.10. After that my first login after reboot takes up to several minutes.

How do I find out the culprit?

Comment: what about the subsequent login?

Comment: You could also post your question at **ubuntuforums.org** in the "Desktop Environments" section.

Comment: You might be able to check some of the logs in /var/log to narrow down the issues.

Comment: +1 on the logs comment.  More specifically: look at the ***timestamps*** in the logs to identify which line(s) are being logged with a great delay after preceding ones.

Answer (score 1):

Bootchart can be a helpful tool in figuring this out, see:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=868189